# Using Stokes theorem to integrate $\vec{F}=5y \vec{\imath} −5x \vec{\jmath} +4(y−x) \vec{k}$ over a circle

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

Find $\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r}$ where $C$ is a circle of radius $2$ in the plane $x+y+z=3$, centered at $(2,4,−3)$ and oriented clockwise when viewed from the origin, if $\vec{F}=5y \vec{\imath} −5x \vec{\jmath} +4(y−x) \vec{k}$

Relevant equations:

> Stokes theorem: $$\int_S \operatorname{curl}{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = \oint_{\partial S} F \cdot d\mathbf{r}$$

My attempt:

- For the curl I get $(4,4,-10)$.
- For $d\vec{S}$ I get $(1,1,1)$ from $z = 3-x-y$
- Dotted together its $-2$.
- So: $-2 \iint_S dA$.
- Area of circle is $4\pi$.

  My answer would be $-8\pi$ but the online homework system says it's not correct. Please help!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to normalize the normal vector.

Comment: Use $\mathbf{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Can someone explain why its 1/sqrt(3)<vector> I thought the sqrt(3) cancels out.

Comment: Because $\mathbf{n}$ is defined as the *outer normal* **unit** *vector* of the surface $S$. In this case $\mathbf{n} = (1,1,1)/|(1,1,1)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Here you have some examples: http://mathinsight.org/stokes_theorem_examples

Comment: I guess I am just confused why ∫curlF⋅ndS= ∫curlF⋅dS

Comment: It is the same thing since $d \vec{S} = \vec{n} \, dS$!

Comment: Oh okay! So what I calculated above was a Scalar without a direction?

Comment: You computed the quantity $\text{curl}{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} dS = \text{curl}{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = -2$, which is scalar magnitude.

Comment: So dS⃗ = (3)^(-1/2)<1,1,1>?

Comment: Of course @Adam! If you want me either to elaborate some more or discuss any other doubt, just tell me. Cheers!

Comment: @Dmoreno This got me the right result(Thank you by the way), but I am confused when I should use ndS or just simply dS. Even in my book it shows dS⃗ as  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}, 1

Comment: For example if I had a surface z=9−x2−y2 why is dS⃗ <2x,2y,1> and not <2x,2y,1>/sqrt(4x^2+4y^2+1)

Comment: Minor comments: it's better to use `\operatorname{curl}` instead of `\mathrm{curl}`, because the former gives correct spacing. Also, "help" is redundant in question titles. Some suggestions on writing titles [are here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x+y+z=3 \implies z = -x-y+3$

$\begin{align} \\ d\vec{S} =\hat{n}dS &= \langle -f_x,-f_y,1 \rangle dxdy\\~\\&= \langle 1,1,1 \rangle dA \end{align}$

you get : $-2\iint_S dA$

So far your work is correct ! there is a mistake in your next step :

$-2\iint_{\color{green}{\mathbb S}} dA \color{red}{\ne} 4\pi $

why ? because **you're assuming that the given circle itself is a shadow in the $xy$ plane**, which is wrong.

since $dA=dxdy$, for the range of $x$ and $y$, you need to take shoadow of $\color{green}{\mathbb S} $  in $xy$ plane :

[image]

If $\alpha$ is the angle between $xy$ plane and $\color{green}{\mathbb S}$, then clearly the area scales by a factor of $\cos \alpha $ :

$\text{Area of ellipse in xy plane} =  (\text{Area of circle in } \color{green}{\mathbb S})\times \cos \alpha =  4\pi \cos \alpha = 4\pi \dfrac{ \langle 1,1,1 \rangle .  \langle 0,0,1 \rangle}{|| \langle 1,1,1 \rangle||} = \dfrac{4\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

well, I think that it is rather a question of getting C in its parametric form.
Your plane is $\Pi :x+y+z=3$.
I will try here to find the orthogonal vectors to the $\Pi$:

let's say that $\underline e_1=(a_1,a_2,0)$ and $\underline{e_2}=(-a_1,a_2,0)$.
Dot product of those vectors with the normal vector of $\Pi$ gives you these 2 eqautions:

$a_1+a_2+a_3=0, -a_1+a_2=0$.

So you can say that $\underline{e_1}= \left(\begin{array}{c}
  1  \\
  1  \\
  -2 
 \end{array} \right)$
and $\underline{e_2}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
  -1  \\
  1  \\
  0 
 \end{array}\right)$

So that your curve parametric form is:
$$C = \sqrt 3 +4 \cos t\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}
  1  \\
  1  \\
  -2 
 \end{array}\right) -4\sin t\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}
  -1  \\
  1  \\
  0 
 \end{array} \right)$$ where $t\in[0,2\pi]$
And from here it becomes much easy.
I hope I helped!

Comment: Since the vector field $\vec{F}$ has a constant curl and, furthermore, the outer normal vector is also constant, I think that this approach is not advantageous and we should therefore take advantage of Stoke's theorem.