# What is the meaning of $d\vec S$ in a surface integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Can someone explain if I have a surface $z= 9-x^2-y^2$

- What would $\vec{n}$ be?
- What would $d\vec{S}$ be?

Why is $d\vec{S}$ $(2x,2y,1)$ and not $(2x,2y,1)/\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}$?
Thanks!

Comment: In this case we probably can guess, but still: where did you encounter $\vec{n}$ or $d\vec{S}$? In general it's hard to answer the question "What would X be" if nothing else about X is told.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if  dS⃗ = n*dS what is n and what is dS?

Comment: It helps if you learn some differential geometry. $\vec n$ can be easily computed by computing first the 2 tangents and then take their cross product, normalize if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose the surface is described using $z=f(x,y)$

$d\overrightarrow{S} = \hat{n}dS =  \langle -f_x, -f_y, 1\rangle dxdy$

$\hat{n} =   \dfrac{\langle -f_x, -f_y, 1\rangle}{||\langle -f_x, -f_y, 1\rangle||}$

$dS = ||\langle -f_x, -f_y, 1\rangle|| dxdy $

In your particular problem :

$d\overrightarrow{S} = \hat{n}dS =  \langle 2x, 2y, 1\rangle dxdy$

$\hat{n} =   \dfrac{\langle 2x, 2y, 1\rangle}{||\langle 2x, 2y, 1\rangle||}$

$dS = ||\langle 2x, 2y, 1\rangle|| dxdy $

Comment: So dS is the product of the magnitude of the vector and dA?

Comment: Exactly! also notice that for a horizontal plane($z=c$), $dS = dA = dxdy$

Comment: So does dS=dA if we have a plane x+y+z=3?

Comment: nope that plane is not horizontal... $dS = ||-1, -1, 1||dA = \sqrt{3}dA $

Comment: so n would be <1,1,1>/$\sqrt(3)$?

Comment: I guess Im really confused now, because I posted a question [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896365/help-with-stokes-problem-of-circle) and Im just now wondering how the square root of 3 stays on the bottom. @Ganesh Tadi

Comment: So it would be $\n$ dotted into <1,1,1>? I'm sorry if I'm asking such simple questions, I am just very lost.

Comment: I think its about the notation : $dS$ is a scalar quantity, multiplying it to the unit normal vector ($\hat{n}$) gives you $d\vec{S}$ ;  for $x+y+z=3$, $dS = \sqrt{3}dA$ and $\hat{n} = \dfrac{\langle 1,1,1\rangle}{\sqrt{3}}$ multiplying them both gives you : $d\vec{S} = \hat{n}dS =  \langle 1,1,1\rangle dA$ . I'll try to reply in that link :)

Comment: Thats what I got at first, but that gave me an incorrect answer, when I was told $d\vec{S}$ was $<1,1,1>$/$\sqrt3$ I received the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, fumbled on my reply earlier. In the more traditional teaching, $\vec ndS=(dydz,dzdx,dxdy)$. After you convert $dydz$ and $dzdx$ into $dxdy$, you will have the correct result. Since $dz=f_xdx+f_ydy$, we have $\vec ndS=(-f_x,-f_y,1)dxdy$, which is the formula given earlier.